# How to manage files in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, function, class

I'm working in Android Studio right now, but I'm a little new to the whole concept of programming. I know how to code in Matlab, and there you create functions and call them inside your code, so you have different files for every task. Here, there are classes and I don't really get it. I have code to generate random numbers without repetition, but I had that code as a function inside the MainActivity.java. I need to use that code several times in the project. Do I have to create a new file with the function and call it from within the code? Or just leave the function inside MainActivity.java?

Sorry if I made some mistakes in English or if the questions is too dumb.

Comment: Instantiate MainActivity.java within another class to call a method contained in that class. However, you are correct, you do not have to use this approach: you can also call a method from within the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to create a new file with the function and call it from
>   within the code? or just let the function inside MainActivity.Java?

You dont need to create a new file ! write your function in  MainActivity.Java like this :

```
private int yourRandomNumberMethod(){//
// your code
}
```

and then call it easily in your activity in **onCreate()** method.
Also i recommend you learn more about JAVA and Android development !

**EDIT:**

> I need to use that code several times in the project. Do I have to
>   create a new file with the function and call it from within the code

For this job create a new class and put your code here, create an instance from this class in where you need the function and call your method with this instance !